# Finding maximum sales in a particular year

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am working on a SQL query and need help with it. I'm using an Oracle database.

The `DAILY_SALES` table holds daily sales amount of each store and each customer; it has following 4 columns:

- STORE_NUMBER`
- CUSTOMER_NUMBER
- TRANSACTION_DATE
- SALES_AMOUNT

Will the following SQL query be able to find out all stores that had more than 20000 dollars in sales in the year of 2013?

```
Select * from DAILY_SALES where SALES_AMOUNT>20000 and TRANSACTION_DATE is in between (Jan1,2013 and Dec31,2013)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I've tried to add some formatting to your question and improve the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question: No. Your query will not work.

Assuming your `transaction_date` column is of type `Date`, then this query should do what you want:

```
select store_number, sum(sales_amount)
from daily_sales
where transaction_date >= to_date('2013-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
and transaction_date < to_date('2014-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
group by store_number
having sum(sales_amount) > 20000
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ..This is the actual query itself or its a pseudo code ?currently I do not have a database to test my sql

Comment: Assuming your column data types are as expected, then yes, this would be the valid Oracle query.  If you want to test it, you can use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to create yourself an Oracle test schema with some test data. From there you can try the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select STORE_NUMBER, TRANSACTION_DATE, SALES_AMOUNT
from DAILY_SALES 
where transaction_date >= to_date('2013-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  and transaction_date < to_date('2014-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
Group by STORE_NUMBER, TRANSACTION_DATE
having sum(sales_amount) > 20000;
```

You want to display only these three columns with these restriction:

- the year of the transaction is in 2013 (from 1/1/2013 right until the
  last day of 2013). You group the results by the STORE_NUMBER and the transaction date.

I think the code above will work for you.

Comment: I think I fixed the errors! Thank you for noticing that. I got confused with MySQL. That's why. Please, if the answer is correct vote up!